# Mysql Reserved Word - how to query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has some reserved words like this:

```
| ID | Name | **DESC**   | SIZE      |
| 1  | A    | round      | 2" L X 3"W|
| 2  | B    | Cubic      | 3" L X 3"W|
```

Here Desc is keyword and is the column name as well. I get an error when I need to fetch data with query like: `SELECT * FROM products where DESC='Cubic';` I get an error with this.

Is there any way to re-design the query (not the table) and get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use backticks to escape the name:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE `DESC` = 'Cubic'
```